# Cygwin not executing .bashrc after Heroku Toolbelt Windows install

Tags: bash, heroku, path, cygwin, heroku-toolbelt

After installing Heroku Toolbelt, Cygwin is no longer executing .bashrc How do I fix this?

This heroku/toolbelt issue on github [Creates/overwrites ENV['HOME'] on Windows, which breaks Cygwin](https://github.com/heroku/toolbelt/issues/28) says to

```
 Renaming HOME to %USERPROFILE% evidently fixes this
```

My HOME System Properties Variable is already named %USERPROFILE%.

Being a noobie I focused on a PATH issue. I began changing my System Path Variable to include the .bashrc PATH

```
C:\cygwin\home\usermatt
```

I then tried various system PATH variables, one at a time, restarting my machine each time:

```
C:\cygdrive\c\home\usermatt\
C:\home\usermatt\
C:\cygwin\c\home\usermatt\
```

Cygwin's pwd on startup is /cygdrive/c/Users/usermatt. I tried moving .bashrc here without success.

The Cygwin FAQs and the comments in the file itself warn of problems after editing the etc/profile file and I did not try this.

All was well before installing Heroku Toolbelt. How can I get Cygwin to find the .bashrc file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the link you provided:

> you need to remove the **HOME** environment variable from the system
>   properties. Look how to set/remove variables from Windows permanently.

This will depend on your Windows OS, but in general:

1. Right click on your "Computer" and select Properties
2. Click on "Advanced System Settings"
3. Click on "Environment Variables..."
4. Find and delete the **Home** variable
5. OK your way out and try Cygwin again

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated, it worked. I see exactly where in the link the solution is. I will read more carefully next time, always learning.